# update value of a object item in local state with a input value using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

What is the correct way to update (concatenate) the input value with the previous value of the item of the object?

Consider the below example:

local states

```
this.state = { model: 'ggg'}
```

In handler

```
handleChange = (event) => {
            this.setState({...this.state,
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
        };
render() {

        const {values} = this.state;
        return (
<TextField
        id="model"
        label="Model"
        name="model"
        value={this.state.model}
        onChange={evt => this.handleChange(evt)}/>
)
    };
```

this is updating the model while I input the characters and update the model as "ggga" "gggaaa".

But I want to update my object in state now.

local states

```
this.state = {values: { model: 'ggg'}}
```

and I tried,

```
handleChange = (event) => {
this.setState(prevState => ({
  values: {
    ...prevState.values,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  },
}))}

<TextField
    id="model"
    label="Model"
    name="model"
    value={this.state.values.model}
    onChange={evt => this.handleChange(evt)}/>
```

Output : "ggga", "gggq"

this is not giving me the expected output.
Can someone please suggest a solution.

Thank you

Comment: Where are you using TextField from?

Comment: In my render method. I updated the question with that

Comment: What I meant was, is TextField a custom component or from a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your state is

```js
{
    values: { 
        model: 'ggg'
    }
}
```

, and you have several attributes in values (more the just `model`) and you only want to update `model`, I would suggest you to do that:

```js
this.setState({
    values: {
        ...this.state.values,
        model: event.target.value,
    } 
});
```

This also works if you have other attributes in your state. As @corrado4eyes, you do not need to pass the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `...prevState` or `...this.state`, you can just use

```
this.setState({
    myProp: newValue
})
```

For what regards what you're asking (how to concatenate the characters) use the onKeyDown/onKeyUp event to get just the character you pressed and concatenate it to the state like that:

```
<TextField
    id="model"
    label="Model"
    name="model"
    value={this.state.values.model}
    onChange={evt => this.handleChange(evt)}
    onKeyDown={evt => this.handleKeyDown(evt)}
/>

.
.
.
.

function handleKeyDown(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        myProp: this.state.myProp + evt.target.value
    })
}
```

Comment: Simply it is working good in my first example you see. I didn't use onKeyDown there.  Can you have any suggestions to update my first example to second one (updating to an object).

Comment: I think [David Alvarez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9478327/david-alvarez) answered for me, ask again if you have doubts